# Reading from CSV file and store to an array

Tags: c#

Can you please help me with C#.
I am trying to create a function in C# that opens a CSV file and save them to an array:

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(guid.ToString(), FileMode.Open);
for (int i = 1; i > 200; i++) // it checks the first 200 lines
{
    int j = 0;
    string[] str = new string[j];
    do
    {                
        // saving each character to the variable until comma is found

    } while(str == '\n'); // read each character in a for loop until new line character found
}
```

Can you please help me out?

Comment: You could cheat by 'borrowing' a nice implementation from the VisualBasis.Net assembly: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx

Comment: Be carefull if you do it yourself, there's some special characters in csv file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(guid.ToString()))
{
    string line;
    int linesCount;
    ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
    while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null && linesCount++ <= 200)
    {
         result.AddRange(line.Split(','));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Parsing CSV by hand is actually pretty tricky. You might be better off reusing the `TextFieldParser` (add a reference to the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` assembly).

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;

....

string[,] parsedCsv;
List<string[]> csvLines = new List<string[]>();
TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(new FileStream(guid.ToString(), FileMode.Open));
parser.Delimiters = new string[] { "," };
parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
int maxLines = 200, lineCount = 0;

try
{
    while (!parser.EndOfData && lineCount++ < maxLines)
    {
        csvLines.Add(parser.ReadFields());
    }
}
catch (MalformedLineException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Line Number: {0} Value: {1}", parser.ErrorLineNumber, parser.ErrorLine);
    return;
}

parsedCsv = new string[csvLines.Count, csvLines[0].Length];

for (int i = 0; i < csvLines.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < csvLines[i].Length; j++)
    {
        parsedCsv[i, j] = csvLines[i][j];
    }
}
```

I have assumed here that the output is going to be a 2-D array of strings - you may need to adjust this code depending on what you are after, especially if you have to cope with the situation where each line does not have the same number of fields (perhaps unlikely, but still).

The really useful thing about `TextFieldParser` is that it will cope with different kinds of delimeters. By setting `parser.Delimiters = new string[] { "\t" };`, for example, this same code could parse tab-delimited text.

Comment: Why go to all this trouble when LINQ does it so nicely with the .Split() extension?

Comment: @JesseCarter try parsing `"a,b,c,\"x,y,z\""` with .Split() and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Fair enough but we have no reason to believe that his file is set up that way. The majority of CSV files that I have ever seen have single CSV entries on each line and can be easily parsed using string.Split on the delimiter

Comment: That's quite true, but making these sorts of assumptions about the format is risky, particularly in view of the fact that the CSV format is more complex than most people think. For example, anything that relies on `ReadLine` is brittle because a quoted CSV field can contain a newline character.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
if(lines.Length >= 200){
    for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++){
          string[] str = lines[i].Split(',');
          //do something here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the string.Split(',') extension method.

```
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(guid.ToString())))
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 200; ++i)
    {    
        string[] str = streamReader.ReadLine().Split(',');
    }
}
```

The Split extension method will return a string array of the individual values separated by a comma.